# Passing class object to method that expects super class object

Tags: java

I have this class heirarchy.

```
class Base {}
class Derived extends Base {}
```

and a method

```
void foo(Class<? extends Base> cls) {}
```

and a variable

```
Class<? extends Derived> derivedCls;
```

Is it possible to call `foo(derivedCls)`?

As written, it fails, complaining that the arguments are incompatible.  `foo` is only going to do a check that some object is an instance of `cls`, so there is no logical problem with the call.  (This is not like passing a `Set<String>` as a `Set<Object>` and then then trying to add an `Integer`.)

`Class::asSubClass` would let me go from `Class<Base>` to 'Class`, but I do not see a method to go the other way.

Comment: You can call `foo(derivedCls)`. What makes you think you can't?

Comment: What is compilation error?